# Pytube долго скачивает

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pytube

Написал программу, чтобы скачивать с YouTube сразу много видео подряд в лучшем из доступных качеств, она работает, всё хорошо, кроме долгой загрузки видео. Если качать через приложение для скачивания видео в браузере, то видео скачиваются очень быстро, буквально меньше секунды, а программы эти же видео скачивает 48 секунд! Почему? Как исправить?

Код программы

```
import pytube
import time

def progress_check(stream=None, chunk=None, file_handle=None, remaining=None):
    # Gets the percentage of the file that has been downloaded.
    percent = int((100*(file_size-remaining))/file_size)
    if percent % 20 == 0 and percent not in past:
        print('%s%%' % percent)
        past.append(percent)


global file_size
global past

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'D:/Kirill/Download'
    video_urls = []  # list from video urls
    url = input("Input URL of a video: ")
    while url:  # while url is not empty
        video_urls.append(url)
        url = input("Input URL of a video or just press Enter: ")
    for i in video_urls:
        start_time = time.time()
        past = []
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(i, on_progress_callback=progress_check)
        video = youtube.streams.filter(adaptive=True).first()
        file_size = video.filesize
        title = video.title
        resolution = video.resolution
        print('Resolution: %s, Size: %s byte, Title: %s' % (resolution, file_size, title))
        print('Your video will be saved to: %s' % path)
        print('Downloaded: ')
        video.download(path)  # path, where to video download.
        print('The video "%s" has downloaded' % title)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        print(' ')
```

Пример вывода

```
Input URL of a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpxMZde62vE&list=PL0bz9dYjS6jMjhwEq0MP4_0w1tD1epIX5&index=6&t=54s'
Input URL of a video or just press Enter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBUCJK-STFo&list=PL0bz9dYjS6jMjhwEq0MP4_0w1tD1epIX5&index=4'
Input URL of a video or just press Enter: 
Resolution: 480p, Size: 13236825 byte, Title: Арсений Тарковский &quot;Жизнь, жизнь&quot;
Your video will be saved to: D:/Kirill/Download
Downloaded: 
0%
20%
40%
60%
80%
100%
The video "Арсений Тарковский &quot;Жизнь, жизнь&quot;" has downloaded
--- 48.40962624549866 seconds ---

Resolution: 480p, Size: 3023536 byte, Title: С утра я тебя дожидался вчера - Арсений Тарковский
Your video will be saved to: D:/Kirill/Download
Downloaded: 
0%
20%
40%
60%
80%
100%
The video "С утра я тебя дожидался вчера - Арсений Тарковский" has downloaded
--- 6.241721153259277 seconds ---
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть issue, и в [одном комментарии](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/180#issuecomment-361998365) говорится, что `on_progress_callback` в `pytube.YouTube`, который просто выводит информацию, может замедлять программу, и помогает его удаление. Может быть, Вам попробовать то же самое?

Comment: Попробовал, --- 48.081151485443115 seconds ---. Не намного быстрее...